# VB.NET: convert text with single quote to upload to Oralce DB

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have a function in VB.NET that runs a query from an MS SQL DB, puts the results into temporary variables, then updates an Oracle DB.  My question is, if the string in the MS SQL contains a single quote ( ' ), how do I update the Oracle DB for something that has that single quote?

For example: Jim's request

Will produce the following error: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

The ueio_tmpALM_Comments (coming from MS SQL) is the culprit that may or may not contain the single quote.

```
update_oracle =
"update Schema.Table set ISSUE_ADDED_TO_ALM = '1'," & _
"ISSUE_COMMENTS = '" & ueio_tmpALM_Comments & "'," & _
"where ISSUE_SUMMARY = '" & ueio_tmpALM_Summary & "' "
Dim or_cmd_2 = New NetOracle.OracleCommand(update_oracle, OracleConn)
or_cmd_2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Please edit your post and show an example of a query which fails in this manner.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question it's clear that you are building the update query using string concatenation.
Something like this

```
Dim myStringVar as string = "Jim's request"
Dim sqlText as String = "UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYNAME = '" + myStringVar + "' WHERE ID = 1"
```

this is a cardinal sin in the SQL world. Your code will fail for the single quote problem, but the most important thing is that this code is subject to [Sql Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You should change to something like this

```
Dim cmd As OraclCommand = new OracleCommand()
cmd.Connection = GetConnection()
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYNAME = :myName WHERE ID = 1"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":myName", myStringVar)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```